# How to create this kind of table?

Tags: html, html-table

i am trying to create this table :
[image]

But so far i stuck with that cell, that spawns 2 columns.
I was trying to use colspan rowspan, but without any success.
My code :

```
            <table class="user-info table">
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th colspan="2"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: The small cells are one cell each. The ***big*** cells are the ones that need to `rowspan`, to stretch over the space of two cells. Same horizontally with `colspan`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this, using the rowspan attribute.

```
<table class="user-info table">
                <tr>
                    <th rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td >&nbsp;</td>
                    <td >&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

See this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xRNsFyiTakf7kDd8ilKW?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<table border="1" class="user-info table">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">COl1</th>
    <th rowspan="2">COL2</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Col3</th>
    <th colspan="2">Col4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>sub head 1</th>
    <th>sub head 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```